# Error de calculadora de fragmentos a través de un diagrama

Tags: java

El diagrama
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El Ejercicio :

```
La clase Fraccion implementa las operaciones suma, resta, multiplicación y división de
fracciones, para la suma y la resta es conveniente usar el método mcm (mínimo común múltiplo
(usar el método de euclides)) para poner ambas fracciones en un denominador común. El método
getValorReal nos devuelve el número double resultado de dividir numerador/denominador. El
método reduce nos devuelve una nueva fracción reducida de la del objeto de que es llamado, p.ej. la
fracción reducida de 4/16 sería 1/4. Y el método toString nos devuelve una cadena que represente a
la fracción (p.ej.: 1/5).
La clase UtilidadesTema05 es una clase de utilidad que implementa los métodos estáticos mcd
(máximo común divisor) y mcm (mínimo común múltiplo)
La clase Main la utilizaremos para poner a prueba a la clase Fraccion. Crea en ella dos objetos de
tipo Fraccion, p.ej. 3/7 y 2/3. Calcula e imprime su suma, resta, producto, división. Imprime
también la fracción reducida de cada una de esas operaciones.
```

El codigo

```
/*
 ___________________
| ******************|
| * @author javie  *|
| ******************|
 -------------------

*/
public class Fraccion {

    private double numerador=0;
    private double denominador=0;

    public Fraccion(double numerador, double denominador) {
        
        this.numerador = numerador;
        this.denominador = denominador; 

    }

    public Fraccion opuesto() {

        return new Fraccion(-this.numerador, this.denominador);
        
    }
    public Fraccion suma(Fraccion q) {
        System.out.print(this.numerador+this.denominador+" ");
        System.out.print("/");
        System.out.print(this.denominador+" ");        
        return q;
    }
    public Fraccion Resta(Fraccion q) {
        return this.suma(q.opuesto());
    }
    public Fraccion inverso() {
        return new Fraccion(this.denominador, this.numerador);
    }
    public Fraccion producto(Fraccion q) {  
        return new Fraccion(this.numerador*q.numerador,this.denominador*q.denominador);
    }
    public Fraccion division(Fraccion q) {
        return this.producto(q.inverso());
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return " "+this.numerador+"/"+this.denominador;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Fraccion p = new Fraccion(3, 7);
        Fraccion q = new Fraccion(2, 2);
        System.out.println("La Suma     : "+p.suma(q));
        System.out.println("La Resta    : "+p.Resta(q));
        System.out.println("La Producto : "+p.producto(q));
        System.out.println("La Division : "+p.division(q));
    }
}
```

Quien me puede decir lo que falla llevo mareaandome la cabeza toda la tarde pero nada. No se en que fallo. Se lo agradecería mucho es para practicar para el examen y quiero saber mi fallo. Y muchas gracias por adelantado a todos por vuestra  colaboraciones. Aqui os dejo el enlace del archivo donde esta el ejercicio. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a8coWcdFZBTqBufHoxRasb6-8KJcdiuz/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estuve mirando mi ejercicio y e encontrado la solución seria la siguiente

**Clase Fraccion**

```
/*
 1) Implementar la clase Fraccion que representa un número racional, p.ej.: 2/3.
 La clase Fraccion implementa las operaciones suma, resta, multiplicación y división de
 fracciones, para la suma y la resta es conveniente usar el método mcm (mínimo común múltiplo
 (usar el método de euclides)) para poner ambas fracciones en un denominador común. El método
 getValorReal nos devuelve el número double resultado de dividir numerador/denominador. El
 método reduce nos devuelve una nueva fracción reducida de la del objeto de que es llamado, p.ej. la
 fracción reducida de 4/16 sería 1/4. Y el método toString nos devuelve una cadena que represente a
 la fracción (p.ej.: 1/5).
 La clase UtilidadesTema05 es una clase de utilidad que implementa los métodos estáticos mcd
 (máximo común divisor) y mcm (mínimo común múltiplo)
 La clase Main la utilizaremos para poner a prueba a la clase Fraccion. Crea en ella dos objetos de
 tipo Fraccion, p.ej. 3/7 y 2/3. Calcula e imprime su suma, resta, producto, división. Imprime
 también la fracción reducida de cada una de esas operaciones.
 */
package boletin;

/*
 ___________________
| ******************|
| * @author javie  *|
| ******************|
 -------------------

*/
public class Fraccion {

    private long numerador;
    private long denominador;

    public Fraccion(long numerador, long denominador) {
        
        this.numerador = numerador;
        this.denominador = denominador; 

    }
    public Fraccion(Fraccion q){
        this(q.numerador,q.denominador);
    }
    public Fraccion opuesto() {
        return new Fraccion(-this.numerador, this.denominador);
    }

    public Fraccion suma(Fraccion q) {        
        if(this.denominador==q.denominador){
            return new Fraccion(this.numerador+q.numerador,this.denominador);
        }
        long numAux,denAux;
        if(this.numerador<0){
            numAux=-this.numerador;
        }else{
            numAux=this.numerador;
        }
        if(this.denominador<0){
            denAux=-this.denominador;
        }else{
           denAux=this.denominador;
        }
        long mcm=UtilidadesTema05.mcm(numAux, denAux);
        return new Fraccion(mcm/this.denominador*this.numerador+mcm/q.denominador*q.numerador,mcm);
    }

    public Fraccion Resta(Fraccion q) {

        return this.suma(q.opuesto());

    }
    public double getValorReal(){
        return ((double)numerador)/denominador;
    }
    public Fraccion inverso() {

        return new Fraccion(this.denominador, this.numerador);

    }

    public Fraccion producto(Fraccion q) {
        
        return new Fraccion(this.numerador*q.numerador,this.denominador*q.denominador);
        
    }

    public Fraccion division(Fraccion q) {

        return this.producto(q.inverso());

    }
    public Fraccion reduce() {
        long numAux,denAux;
        if(this.numerador<0){
            numAux=-this.numerador;
        }else{
            numAux=this.numerador;
        }
        if(this.denominador<0){
            denAux=-this.denominador;
        }else{
           denAux=this.denominador;
        }
        long mcd=UtilidadesTema05.mcd(Math.abs(numAux),Math.abs(denAux));
        return new Fraccion(this.numerador/mcd,this.denominador/mcd);
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if(this.denominador==1){
            return " "+this.numerador;
        }
        return String.format("%d/%d", this.numerador,this.denominador);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        Fraccion p = new Fraccion(3, 7);
        Fraccion q = new Fraccion(2, 3);
        Fraccion r;
        r=p.suma(q);
        System.out.printf("La suma de %s y %s es %s.\n", p,q,r);
        System.out.printf("La version reducida del resultado es de : %s.\n", r.reduce());
        r=p.Resta(q);
        System.out.printf("La resta de %s y %s es %s.\n", p,q,r);
        System.out.printf("La version reducida del resultado es de : %s.\n", r.reduce());
        r=p.producto(q);
        System.out.printf("El producto de %s y %s es %s.\n", p,q,r);
        System.out.printf("La version reducida del resultado es de : %s.\n", r.reduce());
        r=p.division(q);
        System.out.printf("La division de %s y %s es %s.\n", p,q,r);
        System.out.printf("La version reducida del resultado es de : %s.\n", r.reduce());

        
    }
}
```

**Clase UtilidadesTema05**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package boletin;

/**
 *
 * @author javie
 */
public class UtilidadesTema05 {
    public static long mcd(long a,long b) throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException{
        if(a<0 || b<0){
            throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException("Error en los parametros a y b deben de ser positivos.");
        }
        long resto;
        while(b>0){
            resto=a%b;
            a=b;
            b=resto;
        }
        return a;
    }
    public static long mcm(long a,long b) throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException{
        return a*b/mcd(a,b);
    }
}
```